# how to get the value of a tag in soapui with groovy

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:getAttachmentsByCaseIdResponse xmlns:ns2="http://soap.webservice.mod.sub.domain.com/">
         <return>
            <documentClass> A </documentClass>
            <documentId>{C6499CA4-18A8-C56B-84F5-6362E3F00000}</documentId>
            <filename>Image.png</filename>
            <props>
               <entry>
                  <key>CODE_KEY</key>
                  <value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">29210242101077</value>
               </entry>
            </props>
         </return>
         <return>
            <documentClass> Y </documentClass>
            <documentId>{BC359D64-CC71-CC2B-877C-6362E4D00000}</documentId>
            <filename>fileX.pdf</filename>
            <props/>
         </return>
         <return>
            <documentClass>  X </documentClass>
            <documentId>{0000000-000-000-0000-0000000000}</documentId>
            <filename>filename.pdf</filename>
            <props/>
         </return>
      </ns2:getAttachmentsByCaseIdResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have no experience with groovy and I just need a script to return the value of "documentClass" tag if it contains X and then gets the next "documentId" tag content

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XMLSlurper to parse XML content.  More information is available via the API (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) but a quick and dirty example that gets what you need is something like:

```
​import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def text = "" // your XML here
def slurp = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
slurp.Body.getAttachmentsByCaseIdResponse.return?.each {
    println "Class: ${it.documentClass}, ID: ${it.documentId}"
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample xml is a response of a request named TestRequest

```
def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

 def xmlHolder=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("TestRequest#Response")

def xml=  xmlHolder.getXml()

def parser=new XmlSlurper().parseText("xml")
def value=parser.'**'.findAll{it.documentClass.text()=="X"}.collect{it.documentId.text()}

log.info value.toString()
```

The output of the above program is

```
Wed May 16 10:51:42 IST 2018:INFO:[{0000000-000-000-0000-0000000000}]
```

Logic explanation

> First converted the response into xml in a variable named "xml" , then using XmlSlurper retrived the id based on documentClass.  "it" is a groorvy variable which checks all inputs.

if you have inputs like below i.e. spaces you may need to trim or alternatively give like below

```
  it.documentClass.text()=="  X  "

 <documentClass>  X </documentClass>
```